# NativeScript with MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.framework

Tags: ios, azure, nativescript

I am trying to implement azure Speech SDK for NativeScript iOS following [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-microphone-langs/objectivec-ios) but I am getting this error message during build:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/UserName/speechservice/nativescript-azure-cognitiveservices/platforms/ios/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.framework/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/UserName/speechservice/nativescript-azure-cognitiveservices/platforms/ios/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.framework/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech (2 slices)
```

I am able to use the service but having that problem. I have created a custom plugin & added in `Podfile`

```
pod 'MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech-iOS', '~> 1.9.0'
```

As it was `static frameworks` so I have added necessary `module.modulemap`. I am OK to use the service but getting error message during build. Also in apple `appstoreconnect` showing `This build is invalid.`Any suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: Are you running on Simulator? If yes, I guess framework is not compatible with it. You may have to download the universal one that can support both Simulator and Device.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can use the service but getting that error message during build. Also in Apple store it's showing invalid build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech framework is built only for `arm64` and `x86_64`. So disable `32-bit` architectures via `build.xcconfig` like this:

```
VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*] = arm64
VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = x86_64
```